# stat_pvalue_manual() returns different error messages when importing emmeans results to facet plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, p-value, facet-grid, emmeans

I want to add p values from an emmeans test result to a ggplot. The dataset (df) contains two factors (treatment and individuals), one grouping variable which I'd like to use as a row facet, and three different variables (var1, var2, var3), which I want to add eventually as column facets using a molten df (melt_df). Therefore, I ran three different emmeans tests on each variable and bound them together into a single tibble using rbind(). I am only interested in 'individuals' contrasts.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(ggpubr)
    library(rstatix)  
    library(dplyr)
    library(emmeans)
    treatment <- factor(paste("trt", 1:3))
    individuals <- sample(LETTERS, 5)
    fac_var <- c("high", "medium", "low")
    var1 <- sample(1:100, 45) 
    var2 <- sample(1:100, 45) 
    var3 <- sample(1:100, 45) 
        
        df <- data.frame(treatment, individuals, fac_var, var1, var2,var3)
        melt_df <- reshape2::melt(df, id=c("treatment","individuals","fac_var"))
        
        lm_var1 <-   lm(var1 ~ treatment* individuals, data = df)
        emmeans_var1 = emmeans(lm_var1, ~ treatment* individuals)
        pairs_var1 <-  pairs(emmeans_var1, simple="each", by="individuals")
        test_emms_var1<- pairs_var1$`simple contrasts for treatment` %>% 
          summary(infer = TRUE, level = 0.95)%>%
          rbind() 
        
        lm_var2 <-   lm(var2 ~ treatment* individuals, data = df)
        emmeans_var2 = emmeans(lm_var2, ~ treatment* individuals)
        pairs_var2 <-  pairs(emmeans_var2, simple="each", by="individuals")
        test_emms_var2<- pairs_var2$`simple contrasts for treatment` %>% 
          summary(infer = TRUE, level = 0.95)%>%
          rbind() 
        
        lm_var3 <-   lm(var3 ~ treatment* individuals, data = df)
        emmeans_var3 = emmeans(lm_var3, ~ treatment* individuals)
        pairs_var3 <-  pairs(emmeans_var3, simple="each", by="individuals")
        test_emms_var3<- pairs_var3$`simple contrasts for treatment` %>% 
          summary(infer = TRUE, level = 0.95)%>%
          rbind() 
        
        test_emms <- rbind(test_emms_var1, test_emms_var2, test_emms_var3)
        test_emms <- as_tibble(test_emms)
        
        test_emms <- test_emms %>%
          tidyr::separate(contrast, c("group1", "group2"), "-")
        
        dp <- ggplot(melt_df, x = "value", y = "individuals") + 
          geom_point(stat='identity')+
          facet_grid(cols = vars(variable), rows = vars(fac_var), scales = 'free', drop=TRUE)+
          stat_pvalue_manual(data = test_emms, x.position= 2, 
          y.position = "individuals", label = ' p = {p.value}', 
         step.increase = 0, bracket.nudge.y = 1, 
         bracket.shorten = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.8))
```

However, I get this error message:

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "test" is missing, with no default

(The reason why I have so many arguments for 'stat_pvalue_manual()' is because I receive this error message, which persists even if I add all the required arguments):

> Error: ! Problem while computing aesthetics. ℹ Error occurred in the
> 3rd layer. Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`: ! Aesthetics must
> be either length 1 or the same as the data (81) ✖ Fix the following
> mappings: `group`, `step.increase`, `bracket.nudge.y`, and
> `bracket.shorten` Backtrace:
>
> 1. base::print(dp)
> 2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(dp)
> 3. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
> 4. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
> 5. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
> 6. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
> 7. ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
> 8. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)

When I try to add the y position with the emmeans test output using the code below (with and without the 'y' argument for add_xy_position(), I get the following error message:

```
 test_emms <- test_emms %>% add_xy_position(y = "individuals")
```

> Error in add_y_position(., fun = fun, step.increase = step.increase,
> stack = stack,  :    data and formula arguments should be specified.

I tried to add data and formula arguments but I still get error messages when I try to run the code. My guess is that this is because I am using a categorical variable on the y axis instead of a continuous one? Or is it another problem? Could someone help please?

```
    sessionInfo()    
    R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
    
    Matrix products: default
    
    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
    [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    
    
    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
    
    other attached packages:
     [1] pander_0.6.5       ggprism_1.0.4      RColorBrewer_1.1-3 pheatmap_1.0.12    reshape2_1.4.4    
     [6] onewaytests_2.6    reshape_0.8.9      ggpubr_0.5.0       magrittr_2.0.3     emmeans_1.8.2     
    [11] car_3.1-1          carData_3.0-5      rstatix_0.7.1.999  corrplot_0.92      Hmisc_4.7-2       
    [16] Formula_1.2-4      survival_3.4-0     lattice_0.20-45    cluster_2.1.4      factoextra_1.0.7  
    [21] plotly_4.10.1      forcats_0.5.2      stringr_1.5.0      dplyr_1.0.10       purrr_0.3.5       
    [26] readr_2.1.3        tidyr_1.2.1        tibble_3.1.8       ggplot2_3.4.0      tidyverse_1.3.2   
    
    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
      [1] readxl_1.4.1        backports_1.4.1     plyr_1.8.8          lazyeval_0.2.2      splines_4.2.2      
      [6] usethis_2.1.6       TH.data_1.1-1       digest_0.6.30       htmltools_0.5.3     fansi_1.0.3        
     [11] checkmate_2.1.0     memoise_2.0.1       googlesheets4_1.0.1 tzdb_0.3.0          remotes_2.4.2      
     [16] modelr_0.1.10       sandwich_3.0-2      timechange_0.1.1    prettyunits_1.1.1   jpeg_0.1-9         
     [21] colorspace_2.0-3    rvest_1.0.3         ggrepel_0.9.2       haven_2.5.1         xfun_0.34          
     [26] callr_3.7.3         crayon_1.5.2        jsonlite_1.8.3      zoo_1.8-11          glue_1.6.2         
     [31] gtable_0.3.1        gargle_1.2.1        pkgbuild_1.4.0      abind_1.4-5         scales_1.2.1       
     [36] mvtnorm_1.1-3       DBI_1.1.3           miniUI_0.1.1.1      Rcpp_1.0.9          viridisLite_0.4.1  
     [41] xtable_1.8-4        htmlTable_2.4.1     foreign_0.8-83      profvis_0.3.7       htmlwidgets_1.5.4  
     [46] httr_1.4.4          ellipsis_0.3.2      urlchecker_1.0.1    pkgconfig_2.0.3     nnet_7.3-18        
     [51] dbplyr_2.2.1        deldir_1.0-6        utf8_1.2.2          tidyselect_1.2.0    rlang_1.0.6        
     [56] later_1.3.0         munsell_0.5.0       cellranger_1.1.0    tools_4.2.2         cachem_1.0.6       
     [61] cli_3.4.1           generics_0.1.3      moments_0.14.1      devtools_2.4.5      broom_1.0.1        
     [66] evaluate_0.18       fastmap_1.1.0       yaml_2.3.6          processx_3.8.0      knitr_1.41         
     [71] fs_1.5.2            mime_0.12           xml2_1.3.3          compiler_4.2.2      rstudioapi_0.14    
     [76] png_0.1-7           ggsignif_0.6.4      reprex_2.0.2        stringi_1.7.8       ps_1.7.2           
     [81] Matrix_1.5-1        vctrs_0.5.0         pillar_1.8.1        lifecycle_1.0.3     estimability_1.4.1 
     [86] data.table_1.14.4   httpuv_1.6.6        R6_2.5.1            latticeExtra_0.6-30 promises_1.2.0.1   
     [91] gridExtra_2.3       sessioninfo_1.2.2   codetools_0.2-18    MASS_7.3-58.1       assertthat_0.2.1   
     [96] pkgload_1.3.2       withr_2.5.0         nortest_1.0-4       multcomp_1.4-20     hms_1.1.2          
    [101] grid_4.2.2          rpart_4.1.19        rmarkdown_2.18      googledrive_2.0.0   shiny_1.7.3        
    [106] lubridate_1.9.0     base64enc_0.1-3     interp_1.1-3
```

Comment: What packages were you using?  `stat_pvalue_manual` is not in `ggplot2`.

Comment: I found that function in `ggpubr`, but your code still doesn't run.  Please edit it to make it reproducible.

Comment: I used another reproducible example which generates the same error message. I hope that it's clearer now! Thanks.

Comment: Is your code also using `plyr` (for `melt`) and `tidyverse` packages?

Comment: I use dplyr from tidyverse

Comment: I still get your error.  Package versions/results of `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` ?

Comment: I edited the post with sessionInfo output

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error. The issue was that `stat_pvalue_manual` was looking for a column name in `stat.test` that did not correspod to any column in the dataframe used for plotting.

Have a look here:
[got an error after trying to add pvalues manually to a boxplot in ggplot R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68361183/got-an-error-after-trying-to-add-pvalues-manually-to-a-boxplot-in-ggplot-r)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).